# How should be interpreted "(∀x)(∀y)(P(x) ∧ P(y) ⇒ x = y)"?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic, quantifiers

I was reviewing some books of logic and find that the statement "(∃!x)P(x)" is equivalent to "(∃x)P(x) ∧ (∀y)(∀z)(P(y) ∧ P(z) ⇒ y = z)", i understand that "(∃x)P(x)" is read as "there exist a x that, P(x)", therefore "(∀y)(∀z)(P(y) ∧ P(z) ⇒ y = z)" is the part that must indicate that x is unique, but i dont find the way of interpreted it for give it that interpretation, The interpretation that occurs to me is "Every y that P(y), is equal to  every z that P(z)", but, why this mean that x is unique?

Comment: Hmmm, I think your book of logic messed up its lettering. It should be $\operatorname{P}(y)\land \operatorname{P}(z) \implies y=z$- that is, if any two values $y$ and $z$ are such that $\operatorname{P}(y)$ and $\operatorname{P}(z)$, then they are equal. That is equivalent to $\exists !x$ such that $\operatorname{P}(x)$.

Comment: I won't provide a complete answer, but this comment should suffice: to see why $\exists ! xP(x)$ is equivalent to the formulation you state you can use any alternate formulation of unique existence that you are comfortable with, and using natural deduction, verify the two are indeed equivalent. That suffices. As for how would you "read" the formula stated, I would say it's a very artificial formulation of unique existence so it would be tiresome to find a fluent natural language interpretation for it.

Comment: I'm sorry, in the book the letters appear correctly, "y = z", I already corrected it

Comment: Do you see why the sentence $\forall y \forall z \mathop. y = z$ holds if and only if 0 or 1 things exist in our domain of discourse? That is related to how $\forall y \forall z \mathop. P(y) \land P(z) \to y = z$ works.

Comment: That's exactly what I can't see

Comment: The sentence would read as "for all y, for all z, y is equal to z", that mean that every y is equal to every z, and if is right what mean?

Comment: Two P's watbever are identical, that means that there is at most one P (if any).

Comment: It is quite easy to parse it: the existential quantified part expresses "at least one" while the universally quantified part expresses "at most one". The result is: "exactly one".

Answer (score 1):

The statement reads:  For any objects $y$ and $z$: if both $y$ and $z$ have property $P$, then $y$ and $z$ must in fact be the very same one object.

Would this statement be true in any world where there are two or more objects with property $P$?  No, because then one can easily pick two *different* objects that both have property $P$.  So, the statement can only be true if there is at most one objects with property $P$.

Together with the existential that states that there is at least one object with property $P$, you just obtain that there is exactly one object with property $P$

Answer (score -1):

The formula you provided works, but is a bit redundant. I'd suggest:
$$(\exists x) P(x) \wedge (\forall y)(\forall z)(P(y) \wedge P(z) \implies y = z)$$
This essentially just rules out the possibility that there are two different values $y$ and $z$ that both satisfy $P$ but aren't equal.

You could also use:
$$(\exists x) P(x) \wedge (\forall y)(P(y) \implies y = x)$$
Where the scope of the $\exists x$ quantification carries over to the second part of the formula. This says that everything satisfying $P$ is $= x$.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, they are asking why the formula is equivalent to unique existence, and you are totally bypassing that and giving an alternate formula as an answer.

Answer (score -1):

The quantifier that you have encountered is called a [uniqueness quantifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniqueness_quantification). The formula $\exists! x \mathop. P(x)$ reads as "there exists a unique $x$ such that $P(x)$ holds".

The first part $\exists x \mathop. P(x)$ means there is at least one $x$ such that $P(x)$ holds as you noted.

The second part $\forall y \forall z \mathop. P(y) \land P(z) \to y = z$ means that there is *at most one* $x$ such that $P(x)$ holds. The second part by itself does *not* imply existence.

In prose, it reads, *for all entities $y$ and $z$, if $P(y)$ holds and $P(z)$ holds then $y$ is equal to $z$*. This fact does hold if there's one thing satisfying $P$ and does hold if there are zero things satisfying $P$, but fails if there are two or more.

---

Here's a more complete explanation of where that formula comes from using [counting quantifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_quantification) notation.

$$ \exists_{=1} x \mathop. \varphi(x) \;\;\text{is equivalent to}\;\; (\exists_{\ge 1} x \mathop. \varphi(x)) \land (\exists_{\le 1} x \mathop. \varphi(x)) $$

$\exists! x \mathop. \varphi(x) $ and $\exists_{=1} x \mathop. \varphi(x)$ mean the same thing: there exists exactly one $x$ such that $\varphi(x)$ holds.

The expression $\exists_{\ge 1} x \mathop. \varphi(x)$ will be true precisely when some $x$ satisfying $\varphi(\cdots)$ exists, so that conjunct is just $\exists x \mathop. \varphi(x)$.

The expression $\exists_{\le 1} x \mathop. \varphi(x)$ is harder. We need to remember that quantifying over an empty set is vacuously true. Given that observation in mind, we can note that there's at most one $x$ satisfying $\varphi(\cdots)$ precisely when any two values satisfying $\varphi(\cdots)$ have to be equal.

Using a [bounded quantifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantifier) in a totally ad hoc way, we can write this as:

$$ \exists_{\le 1} x \mathop. \varphi(x) \;\;\text{is equivalent to}\;\; \forall y \in \varphi \mathop. \forall z \in \varphi \mathop. y = z $$

And then we can paraphrase away the bounded quantifier, i.e. rewriting $\forall x \in \varphi \mathop. \psi(x)$ to $\forall x \mathop. \varphi(x) \to \psi(x)$.

This gives us:

$$ \exists_{\le 1} x \mathop. \varphi(x) \;\;\text{is equivalent to}\;\; \forall y \mathop. \varphi(y) \to (\forall z \mathop. \varphi(z) \to y = z) $$

Or, equivalently

$$ \exists_{\le 1} x \mathop. \varphi(x) \;\;\text{is equivalent to}\;\; \forall y \forall z \mathop. \varphi(y) \land \varphi(z) \to y = z $$